# SortTableJS not working inside JSP

Tags: javascript, html, sorttable.js

I am developing a website to display data that has to be ordered by the users needs. And I do not know how to solve my problem. I have done all the things that were described [here](https://kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/). But at the end when I run it on the browser it is not working.

This is just the ajax code that is getting the data and returning the table of the **editor view**:

```
    try { 
            /*
                Making call to database 
                and getting all the data
            */

            int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
    %>

                <table id="table" class="sortable table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <% 
                                for(int i=1; i<=count; i++){
                                    %><th scope="col" class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric"><%
                                        out.print(metaData.getColumnName(i));
                                    %></th><%
                                }
                            %>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>
                        <%
                            while(resultSet.next()){%>
                            <tr onclick="rowClickable(this)" class="n_title">
                                   <%for(int i= 1; i<= count; i++){
                                        if(metaData.getColumnName(i).equals("PLANT")){
                                            %><td scope="row" id="clicked"><%
                                                out.println("<a class='disabledLink' href='"+resultSet.getString(i)+"'>");
                                                    out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                                                out.println("</a>");
                                            %></td><%
                                        } else {
                                            %><td><%
                                                out.println(resultSet.getString(i));
                                            %></td><%
                                        }
                                    }%>
                            </tr>
                            <%}
                        %>                
                    </tbody>
                    <tfoot></tfoot>
                </table>
<script src="sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <%      connection.close();
        } 
        catch(Exception e){
            out.println("\n<P> SQL error: <PRE> " + e + " </PRE> </P>\n ");
        }
    %>
```

And this is view of the **browser** code:

```
<table id="table" class="sortable table table-hover table-mc-light-blue">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">PLANT</th><th scope="col" class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">NAME</th><th scope="col" class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">COUNT</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>

                        <tr onclick="rowClickable(this)" class="n_title">
                               <td scope="row" id="clicked"><a class='disabledLink' href='ABI'>
ABI
</a>
</td></tr>

            </tbody>
            <tfoot></tfoot>
        </table>

    <script src="js/plugins/jquery_3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/material.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="../js/created/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And this is my **index.html** page where all the data gets put in:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

        <link href="css/created/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

        <link href="css/plugins/bootstrap-grid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/plugins/bootstrap-grid.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/plugins/bootstrap-reboot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/plugins/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/plugins/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <link href="css/plugins/material.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav id="navbar">  
            <button id="hiddenBackButton" type="button">Back</button>
            <div id="searchNav">
                <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
                    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" id="search" onkeyup="searchFunction('#switch-1',this.value, 'table', 'search')" type="text">
                  <label class="mdl-textfield__label" id="searchLabel" for="sample3" style="margin-bottom: 0.0px">Search by Name</label>
                </div>  
                <div style="width: 10%; display: inline-block;">
                    <span style="
                        cursor: default;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        line-height: 24px;
                        margin: 0;
                        left: 24px">Plant
                    </span>
                    <label class="mdl-switch mdl-js-switch mdl-js-ripple-effect" for="switch-1">
                        <input onclick="changeSearchText(this)" type="checkbox" id="switch-1" class="mdl-switch__input">                        
                    </label>
                    <span style="
                        cursor: default;
                        font-size: 16px;
                        line-height: 24px;
                        margin: 0">Name
                    </span>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </nav>       


        <main id="response_body">
            <div id="p2" class="mdl-progress mdl-js-progress mdl-progress__indeterminate"></div>
        </main>

        <script src="js/plugins/jquery_3.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/material.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.bundle.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="js/plugins/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

        <script src="js/created/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>   

        <script>            
            window.onload = loadDataAjax("response_body");              
        </script>
    </body>       
</html>
```

I hope my code is not too messy or at least readable. It would be great if somebody would be able to solve my problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe you just need to add your script block in the index page (or where the other script tags are injected) ?

Comment: This is just the ajax of the whole website, but inside the index the sorttableJS is linked correctly. Should I put also the index inside the question.

Comment: Did you ensure that the URIs of the javascript resources are OK referred to the JSP's public URI?

Comment: I am sure that the uri´s are all correct

Comment: @StefanNiederwanger <script src="sorttable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
is not present in the rendered page, you might want to inject your script tag alongside the other tags, you might also want to load the script in head section, that way you're sure, its loaded before the table renders.

Comment: The sorttableJS is inserted in the index page. And it is better for the performance, if the scripts are at the end of the body section

Comment: Please make it clear the relationship between the index page (where the sorting does not work) and your JSP (where the sorting does work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem through adding the code below after the function where the table is created:

```
$.getScript('url/to/script');
```

But this code is better described [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/).